# How do I use a JavaScript hash as an argument in a function?

Tags: javascript, hash

JS Newb here.

I'm working with a function, and the documentation for said function says "The argument to the function must be a JavaScript hash where the key is the (database) field to be filtered, and the value is either a string or an array of strings".

Examples that work for me:

```
//New York Knicks fan....
viz.filter({CitiesILoathe: ['Boston']});
viz.filter({CitiesILoathe: ['Boston','Miami']});
```

Either of these snippets work for me, removing said cities from what I see after filter() completes.

Now I want to DIRECTLY pass in a hash which I create/populate earlier.

Can't figure out how.

I've tried:

```
var CitiesILoathe= new Object(); //my "hash"
CitiesILoathe['Boston'] = 1;
CitiesILoathe['Miami'] = 2;
viz.filter({CitiesILoathe}); // also tried same thing w/o curly braces
```

...but no joy. I've been searching thru docs, but my JavaScript vocabulary/intelligence is slow low at this point, I really don't know what I'm looking for.

Can anyone give me a push in the right direction? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//inline declaration
var CitiesILoath = {
    "CitiesILoath": [
        "Boston"
        ,"Miami"
    ]
}
viz.filter(CitiesILoath)

//ad-hoc
var myFilter = {}; //same as "new Object()"
myFilter["CitiesILoath"] = []; //same as "new Array()"
myFilter["CitiesILoath"].push("Boston"); //append to array
myFilter["CitiesILoath"].push("Miami"); //append to array

//or, use decimal notation
var myFilter = {}; //same as "new Object()"
myFilter.CitiesILoath = []; //same as "new Array()"
myFilter.CitiesILoath.push("Bostom"); //append to array
myFilter.CitiesILoath.push("Miami"); //append to array
viz.filter(myFilter)
```

The "Hash" is the object itself.. the "keys" are the fields, in this case "CitiesILoath" and the value for those keys is an array, filled with strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x= { "CitiesILoathe" : [
    "Boston",
    "Miami"
] };
viz.filter(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want an object (it's name doesn't matter, so I'll call it x) which has one property called `CitiesILoathe`. That property is an array, so you can use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add to it:

```
var x = {CitiesILoathe: []};
x.CitiesILoathe.push('Boston');
x.CitiesILoathe.push('Miami');
viz.filter(x);
```

You can also do this like:

```
var CitiesILoathe = [];
CitiesILoathe.push('Boston');
CitiesILoathe.push('Miami');
viz.filter({CitiesILoathe: CitiesILoathe});
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation. Appreciated.